# How to test app store purchase receipt to obtain original application version

Tags: ios

I want to load the app purchase receipt on app launch. How can I simulate an app purchase (not an In-App Purchase, but an actual App purchase) so that I'll have a receipt? (I'm trying to go from paid to freemium).

I'm using this code to load the receipts

```
(BOOL)isAppPreviouslyPurchased {
    BOOL wasPreviouslyPurchased = false;

    // Load the receipt from the app bundle.
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    if (receiptData) {

        //read purchase version from receipt
        NSDictionary *receipt = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receiptData options:0 error:nil];
        NSString *oldVersion = receipt[@"original_application_version"];
        float vFloat = [oldVersion floatValue];

        if (vFloat < 1.6) {
            wasPreviouslyPurchased = true;
        }
    }

    return wasPreviouslyPurchased;
}
```

Comment: One wonders if this is why so many apps have "restore purchases?"

Comment: One wonders why that only works for an in-app purchase... And not an actual APP purchase...Maybe read question before being cynical.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't being cynical, I was just wondering if a similar problem with restoring in-app purchases is an issue.  For in-app purchases, you need a manual trigger, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all : **Refresh your receipt**

```
SKReceiptRefreshRequest *request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

Add the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol and this method

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            // Call the appropriate custom method for the transaction state.
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                [self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:NO];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
                [self showTransactionAsInProgress:transaction deferred:YES];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                // For debugging
                NSLog(@"Unexpected transaction state %@", @(transaction.transactionState));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when this method will be called, your receipt will be refreshed ;)

Secondly : You must **decrypt the receipt**

```
NSData *receipt; // Sent to the server by the device

// Create the JSON object that describes the request
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
    @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
};
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];

if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */ }

// Create a POST request with the receipt data.
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
[storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

// Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (connectionError) {
        /* ... Handle error ... */
    } else {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        if (!jsonResponse) { /* ... Handle error ...*/ }
        /* ... Send a response back to the device ... */
    }
}];
```

You can decrypt it with this code, but it's not really recommended by Apple. You should call iTunes from your server.

Then, you can call your method with the response returned by Apple server.

Like this (with locally validation, bad way as Apple said)

```
NSData *receipt; // Sent to the server by the device

// Create the JSON object that describes the request
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *requestContents = @{
    @"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]
};
NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];

if (!requestData) { /* ... Handle error ... */ }

// Create a POST request with the receipt data.
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
NSMutableURLRequest *storeRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:storeURL];
[storeRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[storeRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

// Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:storeRequest queue:queue
        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (connectionError) {
        /* ... Handle error ... */
    } else {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
        if (!jsonResponse) { /* ... Handle error ...*/ }
          [self isAppPreviouslyPurchased:jsonResponse];
    }
}];

-(BOOL)isAppPreviouslyPurchased:(NSDictionary *)receipt {
    BOOL wasPreviouslyPurchased = false;

        NSString *oldVersion = receipt[@"original_application_version"];
        float vFloat = [oldVersion floatValue];

        if (vFloat < 1.6) {
            wasPreviouslyPurchased = true;
        }

    return wasPreviouslyPurchased;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I get a receipt in the first place? I need it for the actual app purchase. Building from xcode will not give me that.

Comment: Ok, I edit my post. You have to refresh your receipt.

Comment: Refresh your receipt and try it

Comment: could you please tell me how this would go in swift?

Comment: Apple's documentation on receipts is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html