# Check If User Has Purchased Previous App Version

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, app-store

I am moving my iOS app from paid to free and need to know, after the user has installed the update, whether they have purchased the original app.

This way I can reward the user for their previous purchase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test app store purchase receipt to obtain original application version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27569244/how-to-test-app-store-purchase-receipt-to-obtain-original-application-version)

Answer (score 4):

This wasn't possible (easily) before iOS 7 but now it can be down by downloading and parsing the App Store receipt. This is (frustratingly) a lot harder than it sounds. You might want to consider using an Open Source project like [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore).

I [wrote a blog](http://www.zx81.org.uk/computing/programming/moving-an-app-from-paid-to-free.html) about my experience.